# Al instalar JRE o el JDK en Windows no carga dialogo de abrir archivos

Tags: java, oracle, windows7

Les comento a ver si me pueden ayudar que este problema ya me esta volviendo loco. No puedo instalar ni el `JRE` ni el `JDK` de java.

Cuando los ejecuto en el `JRE`, no me aparece nada (pero en el administrador de tareas están 2 procesos) con el `JDK` sucede que aparece una ventana con una barra, esa barra termina de llenarse pero aparece otra ventana donde ya no pasa nada.

He bajado de nuevo el `JDK` y el `JRE`, pero es lo mismo, lo ultimo que hice fue bajar el `JDK 9` y me sale esto de ahí ya no pasa:

[image: Solo esta ventana aparece de ahí ya no he podido que se instale java]

Mi laptop tiene Windows 7 home basic, 4GB de memoria RAM, y un procesador Celeron. Tiene una Intel HD Graphics con 128 MB de vídeo .

Agradezco las respuestas

Comment: y memoria de gráficos?

Comment: Intel HD Graphics con 128 MB de Video

Comment: de cuántos MHz es el celeron?

Comment: Pues descarga otra version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo pienso que te falta memoria de video para poderla instalar de manera gráfica, pero afortunadamente lo puedes hacer desde línea de comandos silenciosamente, para ello desde la consola de windows que obtienes al oprimir <kbd>***⊞***</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> y escribiendo `cmd` deberás de ejecutar el programa con alguna de las opciones que te propongo a continuación.

Tienes las siguientes opciones:

- Instalar JDK y JRE público (no instala código fuente de ejemplo) .

  `jdk-9_windows-x64_bin.exe /s`
- Instalar herramientas de desarrollo y código fuente pero no instalar el JRE.

  `jdk-9_windows-x64_bin.exe /s ADDLOCAL="ToolsFeature,SourceFeature"`
- Instalar las herramientas de desarrollo, código fuente, y JRE público.

  `jdk-9_windows-x64_bin.exe /s ADDLOCAL="ToolsFeature,SourceFeature,PublicjreFeature"`

Más información: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/install/installation-jdk-and-jre-microsoft-windows-platforms.htm#JSJIG-GUID-96EB3876-8C7A-4A25-9F3A-A2983FEC016A

Comment: Excelente colega funciono !! ya pude correr eclipse gracias!!!